When to use string, alias, POSIX path in AppleScript
I'm new to AppleScript and still confused about when to use strings, aliases, or POSIX paths to address files or folders.
For example, in the script below I understand that readmePath is just a concatenated string that probably looks something like path/to/folder/README.md. The same seems to be true for the line do shell script "touch " & quoted form of POSIX path of readmePath but it does not work if I remove POSIX path of .
Why do I need the conversion to POSIX here even though the operation seems to be just the concatenation of two strings?
tell application "Finder"
    set currentFolder to target of front window as string
    set readmePath to currentFolder & "README.md"
    
    if not (exists file readmePath) then
        do shell script "touch " & quoted form of POSIX path of readmePath
        reveal file readmePath
    else
        display dialog "README.md already exists in this folder."
    end if
end tell


Consider a case where your path contains things like /uploads/by-user/evilperson/$(rm -rf ~)/README.md -- you don't want that rm -rf ~ being run as a command; that's what shell-compatible quoting does. If your string is already in an appropriate form, you may not need POSIX path of, but leaving out the quoted form of would be a security risk.

Non-POSIX paths on Apple-y platforms are colon-separated -- :Macintosh HD:Applications:...; converting from those to the /-separated form is what "POSIX path of" does. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html

If your string already looks like path/to/folder, then you don't need POSIX path of.
However, traditional Apple paths are :-separated, not /-separated. If you have path:to:folder, then POSIX path of will convert it into /-separated form (also changing something that starts with :My Volume Name: to properly start with /Volumes/My Volume Name or otherwise the appropriate mount point).

Note that in any event quoted form of is necessary to avoid injection attacks and should not be left out when handling paths coming from anywhere less trusted than your own hand-written and hand-vetted code.

When you ask the Finder to get the target of the front window, it returns an object specifier, e.g. folder "bar" of folder "foo" of startup disk.  Trying to concatenate a string to the specifier will result in an error, since it is not a list, record, or string that you can use with the concatenation operator.  Coercing the specifier to a string first works, since you are then just concatenating strings.
The Finder uses HFS/colon delimited paths (and doesn't understand POSIX), while the shell uses POSIX paths (and doesn't use HFS), so paths need to be coerced as needed when mixing them.
